# What do I do with a question I don't need an answer for anymore?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've asked [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389447/mplab-c-syntax-error-before-token) question, and it turns out I had the wrong source file, and that caused the problem.

Wasted my time, wasted other peoples' time.

What do I do now?

Comment: You might want to link to the question so we can judge the situation. But either you could delete your question, or we could close it as "too localized".

Comment: You.. you.. politician.

Comment: do you still need a question answered?

Comment: Just added link to question. People are adding their comments. I feel like an idiot

Comment: Just delete the question?

Comment: @SamIam  no, I don't need the answer

Comment: Why are you still here?  Go, shoo, delete it

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables just deleted it. I hope the others who helped still get their reputation increased. Somebody show this to the development team.

Comment: No one answered the question. There is a bunch of comments - these _never_ add reputation. Nothing for us devs to do.

Comment: Okay, now that the syntax errors are resolved, I have a real question. Memory allocation or something. It's specific to the PIC24. I'm mixing C and assembly, time pressure is bearing down on me and so on. I suppose I should ask the real question now, if I don't have cooties after this bombs-ola.

Comment: Okay, it looks like you've gone round and round on that question.  I see where you wanted to delete it, then tried to reopen it to answer, etc.  Just delete it.  It is too localized and will have zero benefit to anyone in the future.  Even if you did post an answer and accept it stating that "it was the wrong file" that still won't help anyone.

Comment: @ChrisLively Thanks, voice of experience (about 100x my own) so I take the hit on reputation and will solve the real problem now

Comment: There's no rep hit...

Comment: Hey, I like this place even better now ! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If your question doesn't make sense anymore, than you can delete it.

If you just posted the wrong code but you still need an answer to the question, you can edit your question with the correct code

If you've figured out the answer on your own, than you can post that answer to your question and mark it as accepted.  You won't get any rep for this, but it can let future users understand the solution to the problem.

Comment: But hurry with deleting it, you can't do it anymore as soon as you have upvoted answers.

Comment: Okay, I just deleted it. I hope. Gag I wish I could recover from this.

Comment: @User.1  frankly, you've attracted more attention by posting in this meta topic than you did with the question.

Comment: Stupid fool compiler !!! _error: syntax error before '}' token_  Let's just eliminate the C programming language from planet earth

Comment: @User.1: There's no programming language in the world that would have given the error message "Syntax Error: You are compiling the wrong file"

Answer (score 1):

Delete the question, and no harm done.

If the question may yet become teachable for the future generations, answer it, accept your own answer, and edit for posterity's sake. That's what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253705/cant-load-a-native-dll) - the coding error was all mine, but the error *message* the compiler was spitting out was wildly misleading. Someone may yet make a similar error and spend countless unproductive hours investigating the error message...

Comment: Can I UN-Delete it now that I've deleted it ? Is a wrong source file a teachable thing for the next human who pulls the same stupe-O ?

Comment: Just voted for undeletion. :) Probably takes a moderator or a high-rep user to undelete.

Comment: @User.1 yes you can undelete it.  just revisit the question(probably using the link you posted here) if you wish to undelete it

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev last I checked, if it was the user who deleted it, than the user can undelete it also.

Comment: Just tried to undelete and provide the type of answers you suggested, oops, too late, _This question has been closed - no more answers will be accepted._  Oh well, Hope I haven't killed my reputation too badly.

Answer (score 0):

If someone did try to help you and invested their time in trying to solve your problem, which appears to be the case, I would suggest posting a comment *acknowledging* your error (hard, I know) and then deleting it.

If I was trying to solve a problem being faced by another user, then I would prefer to know what happened, or what had actually gone wrong, rather than having the question deleted without any reason.

Also, I personally think that simply deleting the question would be disrespecting the effort that others are putting in.

You could also upvote an answer or two of theirs' that you think are good, as a way to acknowledge their effort.

Comment: My exact thoughts, but I just deleted the question

Comment: You always have the option to undelete your own questions if you were the one to delete them (no need to go through any review queue).

Comment: Just to clarify only a mod can delete questions with answers. So the only "effort" would be the comments.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter The *comments* were trying to pinpoint the problem and thus reach the solution.

Comment: @AshRj right but as the [comment faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/148672) says  *Comments are disposable: unlike posts, there's no revision history, and they can be deleted without warning by their authors, by moderators, and in response to flags.* So if you're putting effort into something that is disposable...